# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource and BeanFactory not initialized or already closed

Tags: spring-security, struts2

I'm new to struts2. I'm try to apply spring security on my struts2 application. I'm following this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/spring-security-3x/9781782167525/ch02s02.html).I'm getting this error. Help please. Thanks.
my web.xml is

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>`
```

and my applicationcontext-security.xml is

```
`<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org
/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org
/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org
/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-
beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-
security-4.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <!-- AspectJ pointcut expression that locates our "post" method and applies 
            security that way <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* bigbank.*Service.post*(..))" 
            access="ROLE_TELLER"/> -->
    </global-method-security>
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed?error=true" />
        <logout />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="anjana" password="packt123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>`
```

and my struts.xml is `

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="helloWorld">
            <result>success.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="login">
            <result>login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="loginfailed">
            <result>login.jsp?error=true</result>
        </action>

        <action name="welcome">
            <result>index.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

`console message is`

```
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Spring_Security_Struts2' did not find a matching property.
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 18 2015 11:38:37 UTC
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.26.0
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\jalagarip\Documents\GitHub\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\jalagarip\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\jalagarip\Documents\GitHub\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\jalagarip\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\jalagarip\Documents\GitHub\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\jalagarip\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.26\endorsed
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\jalagarip\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\jalagarip\curl;C:\Program Files\cURL\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin;;C:\Users\jalagarip\Desktop;;.
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1025 ms
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.26
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:03 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 04 12:05:04 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 21 more

Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:509)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 21 more

Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Spring_Security_Struts2] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 04 12:05:04 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 04 12:05:04 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:969)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:928)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4776)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:976)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:928)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4776)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 04, 2015 12:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3788 ms
```

`

Comment: Create a `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` file, include your security configuration into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with the name of the configuration file as I followed that link.
The name used was different at different places in that link.Thanks.